# $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{x+2} = 1/3$ with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit to prove that
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{x+2} = 1/3.
$$

But I'm getting stuck on finding the correct $\delta$. Here is my try:

\begin{align*}
\lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon \\
\lvert  \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3} \rvert < \varepsilon \\
\lvert  \frac{x -1}{2 + x} \rvert < 3\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

And then I'm not really sure what to do. How do you proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far you have deduced a chain of equivalences, and I will add one more to the chain:
\begin{align*}
& \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon \\
\iff & \lvert  \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3} \rvert < \varepsilon \\
\iff & \lvert  \frac{x -1}{2 + x} \rvert < 3\varepsilon \\
\iff & \lvert x-1 \rvert < 3 \, \epsilon \, \lvert 2+x \rvert
\end{align*}
Reading this chain of equivalences backwards, you have proved so far that
$$\lvert x-1 \rvert < 3 \, \epsilon \, \lvert 2+x \rvert \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon
$$

Your goal now is to find a value of $\delta>0$ such that
$$ \lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta \implies  \lvert x-1 \rvert < 3 \, \epsilon \, \lvert 2+x \rvert
$$
for then you will be done.

The first step towards finding $\delta$ is to work with the factor $\lvert 2+x \rvert$ separately. Your goal in this step is to find any lower bound to that factor. Intuitively, if $x$ is close to $1$ then it must be far from $-2$. To make this intuition rigorous, note that
$$\lvert x-1 \rvert < 1 \implies -1 < x-1 < +1 \implies 2 < x+2 < 4 \implies 2 < \lvert x+2 \rvert 
$$
Summarizing, we have found $\delta_1 = 1$ for which the following implications hold:
$$\lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta_1 \implies \lvert x-1 \rvert < 1 \implies 2 < \lvert 2+x \rvert \implies 6 \epsilon < 3 \epsilon \lvert 2+x \rvert
$$
Now we set $\delta_2 = 6 \epsilon$.

Assuming already that $\lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta_1 = 1$, if in addition we assume that $\lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta_2 = 6 \epsilon$ then it follows that
$$\lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta_2 = 6 \epsilon < 3 \epsilon \lvert 2+x \rvert
$$
And now we have found $\delta$, namely:
$$\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}
$$
Putting this altogether, assuming that $\lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta$ it follows that $\lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta_1 = 1$ and $\lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta_2 = 6 \epsilon$ and therefore
$$\lvert x-1| < 3 \epsilon \lvert x+2 \rvert
$$
This, as we have already shown, implies that $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=1+\delta$. Then we have:

$$\lim_\limits{\delta\to0} \left|\frac{1}{3+\delta}-\frac{1}{3}\right|$$

$$=\lim_\limits{\delta\to0} \left|\frac{\delta}{3+\delta}\right|$$

Letting $\delta=\epsilon$ means that for any $0<\epsilon<1$, the expression in the limit is less than $\epsilon$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

The last inequality should be $|\frac {x-1} {2+x}| <3\epsilon$. Use the fact that $|2+x|=|3+(x-1)| \geq 3-|x-1|$. What you now need is $\frac {|x-1|} {3-|x-1|} <3\epsilon$. Cross multiply and will get the inequality in the form $|x-1| <\delta$ where $\delta=\frac {9\epsilon} {1+3\epsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to see this, but stuck even on your first sentence. $$\abs{\frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3}} \iff \abs{\frac{3}{3(x+2)} - \frac{(x+2)}{3(x+2)}} \iff \abs{\frac{3 - x - 2}{3(x+2)}} \iff \frac{1}{3}\abs{\frac{1 - x}{x+2}} \iff \frac{1}{3}\abs{\frac{-(x-1)}{x+2}}.$$ What happend to the negative sign in your answer?

Comment: @djaysten $\frac 1 {x+2}-\frac 1 3=\frac {1-x} {3(2+x)}$

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. So why do you have $\lvert \frac{x-1}{2+x}\rvert < 3\varepsilon$ in your asnwer? Shouldn't it be $\lvert \frac{1 - x}{2+x}\rvert < 3\varepsilon$?

Comment: @djaysten $|-(x-1)|$ is same as $|x-1|$.

Comment: $\lvert 3 + (x-1) \rvert \geq 3 - \lvert x -1 \rvert$. Here we have a lower bound. But when we take the reciprocal, we have an upper bound on $\frac{1}{\lvert 3 + (x-1) \rvert }$. How do we know this new expression is still less than $3\varepsilon$?

Comment: $\frac {|x-1|} {3-|x-1|} <3\epsilon$ is same as $|x-1| <9\epsilon -3\epsilon |x-1|$. Transfer the last term to the left side and divide by $1+3\epsilon$. @djaysten

Comment: $\frac {|x-1|} {|3+(x-1)|} \leq \frac {|x-1|} {3-|x-1|}$, based on your inequality. What if $ \frac {|x-1|} {3-|x-1|} \geq 3 \varepsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there should be $\left|\frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{3}\right| = \left|\frac{x -1}{2 + x}\right|\cdot \frac{1}{3}$

After this, one more possible way is choose such neighbourhood of $x=1$, in which $|2+x|$ can be estimated from below. For example, when $\delta \lt 1$, then $|2+x| = 2+x \gt 1$. Now we have $\left|\frac{x -1}{2 + x}\right| \lt  |x-1|\lt \delta $. Are you able to finish from here, taking in account factor $\frac{1}{3}$?

Answer (score 0):

As the function is monotonic around $x=1$ (provided $\delta<3$), you can solve

$$\frac1{1+\delta+2}-\frac13=\pm\epsilon$$

which gives

$$\delta=\mp\frac{9\epsilon}{1\pm3\epsilon}.$$

Then take the smallest of the two absolute values,

$$\delta=\frac{9\epsilon}{1+3\epsilon},$$ which is the tightest possible.

Below, $\epsilon=\dfrac1{10}$ and $\delta=\dfrac9{13}$.

[image]